# Rewriting Riemann sum as integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

Can anybody tell me how to rewrite this sum limit as integral 
I am struggling with converting this equation into definite integral form

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\ln{\left(5k+n\right)}-\ln{(n)}}{n}$$

Here is the original question:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2pUj.png)

Comment: What have you tried? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the summation using log properties:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\ln{\left(\frac{5k}{n}+1\right)}}{n}$$
This way, $x=\frac{k}{n}$ and $dx=\frac{1}{n}$.
$$\int_0^1 \ln{\left(5x+1\right)} \; dx$$
Try finishing it.